# issue with For loop c++

Tags: c++

This code suppose to print the dropped student IDs in certain range between start and end, and when I run it the program crashes.. any suggestions?
the input is array of IDs [12001,12002,12003,12006]
the desired output: 12004 , 12005 // the dropped IDs between 12001 and 12006

```
void dropped_students(vector<string> students_id){
    // creating array of numbers between max and min
    int start = min_id(students_id) , end = max_id(students_id);
    vector<int> numbers;
    string diff_number;
    for (int i = start ; i <= end ; i++ )
        numbers.push_back(i);
    // finding the drooped numbers
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.size(); i++){ 
        int found = 0;
        int num = atof(students_id[i].c_str());
        for (int j = 0 ; j < students_id.size() ; j++){
            int stu_id = atof(students_id[j].c_str());
            if (stu_id == num) 
                found = 1;break;
        }
        if (found == 0)
            {cout<< num << endl;}
    }       
}
```

Comment: "any suggestions?" You should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and descrive the desired behavior to post questions here.

Comment: Your code is badly formatted..and you haven't expressed what was your intended output and where have you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You have more items in "numbers" than in "studends", nevertheless you use "students_id[i]" where "i" is the index within "numbers" => this is out of range.

I think this line

```
int num = atof(students_id[i].c_str());
```

should be

```
int num = numbers[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way to optimize your function:

1. Sort array by numeric value of student id
2. Scan through student array, locate gaps and output them

The function may look like the following:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool CompareIDs(string students_id1, string students_id2) {
    return atoi(students_id1.c_str()) < atoi(students_id2.c_str());
}

void dropped_students(vector<string> students_id){
    // creating array of numbers between max and min
    sort(students_id.begin(), students_id.end(), CompareIDs);
    bool first = true;
    int last;
    for (auto strid : students_id) {
        int id = atoi(strid.c_str());
        if (!first) {
            if (id>last+1) 
            for (int i = last + 1; i < id; i++)
                cout << i << endl;
        }
        last = id;
        first = false;
    }
}
```

I tested it with this main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<string> students_id;
    students_id.push_back("12001");
    students_id.push_back("12002");
    students_id.push_back("12003");
    students_id.push_back("12006");
    dropped_students(students_id);
}
```

and it printed:

```
12004
12005
```